# Why isn't ng-repeat working here?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array within my scope called `checkedInChildren`. The array contains just string values. I want a table to repeat for each string in the `checkedInChildren` array. Here is what I have so far:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="child in checkedInChildren">
          <td>test</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.checkedInChildren = [];

  $scope.addChildToCheckedIn = function(childName) {
    $scope.checkedInChildren.push(childName);
  }

});
```

No rows show no matter what names I add to that array. I omitted some code in the controller and some of the HTML, but I am debugging and clearly seeing values in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you do `{{checkedInChildren}}` in your html file and see whether list is displayed. Any errors in console?

Comment: Considering $scope.addChildToCheckedIn working properly,
Make sure that childName is not undefined/same values. try "child in checkedInChildren track by $index"

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `{{child}}` to bind each item to the view.

```
<tr ng-repeat="child in checkedInChildren">
  <td>
    {{child}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I did do that at first. I switched it to just display the word 'test' to see if that would make a difference. It did not work when I had {{child}} in the column either.

Answer (score 0):

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ku7WGNVrnUNY2Pa4QG4d?p=preview)

It is not displaying `test` because there is no item in your `checkedInChildren` array.

[From Angular Doc:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

> The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a
>   collection.

```
  $scope.checkedInChildren = [];

  $scope.addChildToCheckedIn = function (childName) {
        $scope.checkedInChildren.push(childName);
  }

  $scope.addChildToCheckedIn('John');
```

You did not call `addChildToCheckedIn` method, that is why `checkedInChildren` array is empty.

hope that solve your problem.

Comment: I am calling and inserting values into the array. I can see values in the array in the debugger.

Comment: @halterdev, can you add any Fiddle/Plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

on your HTML you're referencing a different controller, put the proper name

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="checkInCtrl">...</div>
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VKyGEp?editors=1010)

Answer (score -1):

Did you call the `addChildToCheckedIn` function? [Try](https://jsfiddle.net/DieuNQ/8tuuwps4/) this. Hope this helps.